# Tennis coaches who were former opponents of the players they coached

Tags: history, tennis

Brad Gilbert and Andre Agassi played [8 ATP matches](http://www.atpworldtour.com/Players/Head-To-Head.aspx?pId=G016&oId=A092) before Gilbert retired as a tennis player and later became Agassi's coach.

Amelie Mauresmo and Marion Bartoli played [5 WTA matches](http://www.wtatennis.com/head2head/player1/5394/player2/1007) before Mauresmo retired as a tennis player and later became Bartoli's coach.

I am sure there are more examples like these in the world of tennis, but cannot think of any. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sampras and Paul Annacone played once. Agassi and Darren Cahill also played twice during the overlap of their careers. I would imagine some of the younger coaches (like Roger Rasheed for example) might have played some of the players they've coached.

Comment: I just checked for Roger Rasheed, he is not one of the examples, hence I'll remove the part mentioning him in your answer.